# calling a function in R script

Tags: function, rscript

I wrote a R script in which I wrote a function and called the function. here is the whole script:

```
PrepData = function(infile){
        data <- read.table(infile, header=TRUE, as.is = TRUE, sep = ",")
        data = data[, 2:ncol(data)]
                 merged.data = data
        colnames(merged.data[1]) < "CodeCount"
        rownames(merged.data) <- merged.data$Name
        x <- list(counts = merged.data, raw.counts = merged.data)
 return(x)
}



data <- PrepData(myfile.csv)
data
```

but when I run it using the following command:

```
Rscript myscript.r
```

it gives this error:

```
Error in read.table(infile, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, sep = ",") : 
  object 'myfile.csv' not found
Calls: PrepData -> read.table
Execution halted
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Did the answer fix it? :)

Comment: @Artoiss: yes that was it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
data <- PrepData(myfile.csv)
```

To

```
data <- PrepData("myfile.csv")
```

You need to have quotation mark on the filename when you use read table function.